# Singleton pattern + __construct in PHP4

Tags: php, singleton

**To clarify:**

- no I can't make this pure PHP5
- yes  this code works in PHP 4.3.9.

I don't have any real world experience implementing or supporting PHP4 but I had to recently change my class so it supports both PHP4 and PHP5.

- Can anyone foresee any possible issues in regards to my implementation of the singleton method used here? I only want one instance of this class.
- I know I could completely get rid of the `__construct` method, should I? ( and move the function body of it to the Conf function ).
- Could I have used `self` anywhere? I wasn't sure of its PHP4 support.

---

```
<?php

class Conf {
    function Conf( $filename ) {
        $this->__construct( $filename );
    }

    function __construct( $filename ) {
        echo $filename;
    }

    function getInstance( $filename ) {
        static $instance = null;
        if ( $instance == null ) {
            $instance = new Conf( $filename );
        }
        return $instance;
    }
}

$x = Conf::getInstance( 'file.xml' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around the unavailability of `self` in PHP4, you should change your `getInstance` method to the following:

```
class Conf {
    function Conf( $filename ) {
        $this->__construct( $filename );
    }

    function getInstance( $filename ) {
        static $instance = null;
        if ( $instance == null ) {
            $class = __CLASS__;
            $instance = new $class( $filename );
        }
        return $instance;
    }

    // Don't forget to block cloning
    function __clone() {
        trigger_error("Cannot clone a singleton", E_USER_WARNING);
    }
}
```

Edit: Because `__CLASS__` will always be the class name of the class in which the function was defined, to support inheritance, you must redefine the `getInstance` method in every child class.

```
class Conf2 extends Conf {
    function newMethod() { echo "Do something"; }

    function getInstance( $filename ) {
        static $instance = null;
        if ( $instance == null ) {
            $instance = new self($filename);
        }
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

It's a drag, yes, but if you use the above method, you can just copy and paste.  I believe this is fixed in PHP 5.3 with [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), but I haven't installed it yet to confirm.

Comment: Interesting. So is that `__CLASS__` basically a replacement for `self` since PHP4 can't support `self`?

Comment: Yup, `__CLASS__` is a magic constant (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unnecessarily complex. You don't need the __construct method at all if you have the other one. (or vise versa, however, older versions of php don't support __construct)

Also, to implement the singleton pattern properly, the static instance should be class scope, and the constructor should be private.

```
class Singleton {
    private static $instance;

    private function Singleton(){
        //do stuff
    }

    function getInstance(){
        if(self::$instance == null){
            self::$instance = new Singleton();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

[This article](http://abing.gotdns.com/posts/2006/php4-tricks-the-singleton-pattern-part-i/) describes how to implement the Singleton Pattern in PHP4, and it's problems.

Comment: yes I'm aware of the `__construct` deal, I guess I should just kill it entirely.

Could you demonstrate how you would do it properly?

Comment: also a thing to be aware of is __clone() it can duplicate the object and if you don't want that happening (which shouldn't be allowed in a true singelton pattern) you should override it and return null, or die.

Comment: @Malfist - your updated code is exactly how I had my PHP5 code. I'm aware of that article, I was just looking for advice for someone who knew exactly the tricks implemented in said article in my context.

Comment: The OP asked for PHP4 compatibility.